# Boostrap 5, is-valid and empty field howto?

Tags: bootstrap-5

From the documentation (it's what I've understood): when a form is posted to our server, we check it, if it's not valid, me return it. In such case, we must add `class="was-validated"` to the form, and we me must precise for all fields, whether it's good (add class `is-valid`) or not (add class `is-invalid`).

In our case, **we do accept empty fields as valid**. So we return some fields with class `is-valid` and because the fields are empty, bootstrap *still shows the red outline*, not the green, like this:

[image]

The form code is :

```
<form action="" method="post"
      class="was-validated" novalidate>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <label for="id_content2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Content2</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="content2" class="form-control is-valid"
                required id="id_content2" aria-describedby="content2" />
        <div class="valid-feedback"> Valid </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the solution to consider some empty fields as valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that the "is-valid" is being added when the form is returned to the user but the field is empty. That would explain the behaviour at least...

One solution to consider an empty field as valid is to remove the "required" attribute from the input field and check if the field is empty on the server side before processing the form.

Comment: That was it! Django creates form fields with the attribute `required` by default. Thanks!